# convert vector<char> first N elements to an integer

Tags: c++

How Can I convert first `HEADER_LENGTH` of a `std::vector<char>` to an integer?

Here `HEADER_LENGTH` is the message size and `std::vector<char>` is the whole message.

**UPDATE**:

To clarify, It is combining first N elements, not just converting them separately.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't get your idea? You want to combine first HEADER_LENGTH of vector<char> to an integer by each decimal digit or memory location? For example, vector<char> a = {'0','1','2','3'} and you want to get 4 element to integer then the result would be 123 (each char present a digit) or 858927408 (combine value of 4 memory location into an int)?

Comment: Yes, combine first HEADER_LENGTH elements to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your exactly idea so I do both my guesses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> a = {'0','1','2','3','4'};

//My sample is for HEADER_LENGTH of 4

    // by memory content
    int x;
    memcpy(&x, a.data(), 4);
    cout << x << endl; //858927408

    // by digit
    x = 0;
    for (auto it = 0; it < 4; it++) {
        x = x * 10 + (a[it] - '0');
    }
    cout << x << endl; //123
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a for loop to iterate over HEADER_LENGTH chars of the vector and then convert them.

```
for(int i = 0; i < HEADER_LENGTH; i++)
{
    vector[i]; // convert char to int here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process each `char` like you'd do with array elements. You can convert a `char` type to `int` simply by assigning it to `int`. A `char` is just a 1 byte integer. In ASCII code, numbers start from 48. So;

```
vector <char> arr;

for(int i = 0; i < HEADER_LENGTH; i++) {
    int x = arr[i] - 48; 

    //or 

    int x = arr[i] - '0';
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Try to be explicit. Use '0' instead of 48.